# C++ With OpenGL and GLM libraries how do you create a simple 2d rotation without stretching of the primitive into 3d?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have been using OpenGL in addition to GLM, Glad, and GLFW to create a 2d game. I want to achieve a simple 2d rotation, presumably along the Z-axis because it would not be 3d. The problem is, when I create a simple model matrix that uses a rotation matrix multiplied with a translation and dilatation matrix, the rotation becomes 3d when the primitive is rendered. The square is stretched and the sides are no longer the same length. Is there a way to avoid this stretch so that the square remains the same proportions while it rotates?

Vertex Shader:

```
//shader vertex
#version 430 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
//uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 model;

out vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

I have a function that iterates through vectors of matrices to handle large batches of objects. The matrices are first created to equal glm::mat4(1.0f).

```
void Trans::moveBatch(std::vector <glm::vec2>& speed, std::vector <float>& rot)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < speed.size(); i++)
    {
        batchRotator[i] = glm::rotate(batchRotator[i], glm::radians(rot[i]), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        batchMover[i] = glm::translate(batchMover[i], glm::vec3(speed[i].x, speed[i].y, 0.0f));
        batchBox[i].x += speed[i].x;
        batchBox[i].y += speed[i].y;
        batchBox[i].z += speed[i].x;
        batchBox[i].w += speed[i].y;
    }
}
```

I then multiply my matrices and send that as the model matrix into the shader.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on how to ask a question.  There's no general reason that proper x-y transformations on objects in a plane like z=0 will produce results not in the plane. Consequently, there's no way to answer your question without seeing the code that contains your error. SO has some very smart people, but no clairvoyants afaik. :)

Comment: Makes sense, I figured that because OpenGL renders everything in 3d that this was default. I'll edit to add some code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 3D. This is just because you ignore the aspect ratio of your viewport,

Comment: Your transformation is correct. What you need is a projection matrix that handles the aspect ratio of the viewport. See [LearnOpenGL - Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I was able to use glm::ortho to create a projection matrix and that solved my problem when I made the world coordinates within 1920/1080 because that was the correct aspect ratio.